# mysqli Parameter Error - DB Connection Working Fine?

Tags: php, mysqli, error-handling, row

I am adding a value to a column in one of my tables. My goal is to have the column data show on the page through a table. However, when I add in this code (to loop through the table and show the data), I get an error:

```
<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $customer_name = $row['customerName']; 

echo "<tr>
        <td>$customer_name</td>
     </tr>";

    } // end while loop  
?>
```

ERROR

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in
>   xxx on line
>   35

I have done some research on this error, I've seen responses saying the database connection could be incorrect. However, I checked my database and the value is indeed being entered in the table as it should, so there is no issue connecting to or querying the database.

I have also commented out the above code, and the HTML shows fine as well. I have isolated the issue to being with the while/array code above. The error only appears when that segment of code is added into the script.

Please let me know if you find any insights in what could be the issue with the error, and the table not displaying. I've used the same type of code for a similar script and have never set a parameter, and it's worked fine.

Here is the full code if needed:

```
<?php
require_once("./includes/database_connection.php");

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$query = "INSERT INTO customers(customerName) VALUES('IKB')";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
    or die ('Error querying databse');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="classic_cars.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        require_once("./includes/navigation.php");
    ?>

    <table>
        <tr>    
            <td>customerName</td>
        </tr>
    </table>    

    <?php

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $customer_name = $row['customerName']; 

    echo "<tr>
            <td>$customer_name</td>
         </tr>";

        } // end while loop  
    ?>

    <?php
        mysqli_close($dbc);
        require_once("./includes/footer.php");
    ?>      
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the DB Connection:

```
<?php
    define('DB_LOCATION', 'x');
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'x');
    define('DB_PASS', 'x');
    define('DB_NAME', 'x');

    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_LOCATION, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASS, DB_NAME)
        or die('Error connecting to database'); 
?>
```

Comment: please post the contents of "database_connection.php"

Comment: @Abdo Adel Sure thing, added it in the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), section on Return Values:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Your query is an `INSERT`, so the return type will be boolean TRUE or FALSE. That is why `$result` is a boolean instead of a mysqli_result object.

It seems that, at least in your example code, you already know the customer name at the beginning in order to do the `INSERT` so why not just save that value to reuse later on? Otherwise if you really do need to retrieve the full record from the database again for whatever reason you would need to do a new `SELECT` query before doing `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))`.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$query = "INSERT INTO customers(customerName) VALUES('IKB')";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die ('Error querying databse');
```

to

```
$query = "INSERT INTO customers(customerName) VALUES('IKB')";
mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die ('Error querying databse');
$query2 = "select customerName from customers";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2) or die ('Error querying databse');
```

**Explanation**

- `mysqli_fetch_array` expects the first parameter to contain a result set, executing DDL statements such as `insert into customers...`does not return the new table rows after insertion but it returns whether the operation was successful or not(true/false), that's why the error says *mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given*
- To fix the problem, first we execute the `insert` query, then we execute another `select` query that retrieves table rows after successful `insert`